# Django migrate: django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1364, "Field 'name' doesn't have a default value")

Tags: python, mysql, django, mariadb

basic datas:

```
mysql-server: 5.7.27-0ubuntu0.16.04.1
Ubuntu: 16.04
Python: 2.7.12
Django: 1.11.16
Virtualenv
```

I added a new application (gallery) and created the following table:

```
class Medi(models.Model):
    gd_id = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=512, default='1')
    original_name = models.CharField(max_length=512)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=512, blank=True, null=True)
    md5sum = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    date_of_event = models.DateTimeField()
    date_of_event_end = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    last_updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

To be very clean after getting the above mentioned errors I deleted the table from the database, the entries from the django_migrations table and all the migrations file but `__init__.py`.

I ran `makemigrations` and after that `migrate` which had the following output:

```
# python manage.py makemigrations
Migrations for 'gallery':
  gallery/migrations/0001_initial.py
    - Create model Medi

# python manage.py migrate
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: admin, auth, bugtrack, common, contenttypes, follow, gallery, infokom, phonebook, sessions, sites
Running migrations:
  Applying gallery.0001_initial... OK
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/lenovo/.virtualenvs/gjt/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 364, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/lenovo/.virtualenvs/gjt/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 356, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/lenovo/.virtualenvs/gjt/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 283, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/home/lenovo/.virtualenvs/gjt/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 330, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/home/lenovo/.virtualenvs/gjt/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 227, in handle
    self.verbosity, self.interactive, connection.alias, apps=post_migrate_apps, plan=plan,
  File "/home/lenovo/.virtualenvs/gjt/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/sql.py", line 53, in emit_post_migrate_signal
    **kwargs
  File "/home/lenovo/.virtualenvs/gjt/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/dispatch/dispatcher.py", line 193, in send
    for receiver in self._live_receivers(sender)
  File "/home/lenovo/.virtualenvs/gjt/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/management/__init__.py", line 63, in create_permissions
    ctype = ContentType.objects.db_manager(using).get_for_model(klass)
  File "/home/lenovo/.virtualenvs/gjt/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/contenttypes/models.py", line 60, in get_for_model
    model=opts.model_name,
  File "/home/lenovo/.virtualenvs/gjt/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/lenovo/.virtualenvs/gjt/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 466, in get_or_create
    return self._create_object_from_params(lookup, params)
  File "/home/lenovo/.virtualenvs/gjt/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 500, in _create_object_from_params
    obj = self.create(**params)
  File "/home/lenovo/.virtualenvs/gjt/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 394, in create
    obj.save(force_insert=True, using=self.db)
  File "/home/lenovo/.virtualenvs/gjt/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 808, in save
    force_update=force_update, update_fields=update_fields)
  File "/home/lenovo/.virtualenvs/gjt/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 838, in save_base
    updated = self._save_table(raw, cls, force_insert, force_update, using, update_fields)
  File "/home/lenovo/.virtualenvs/gjt/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 924, in _save_table
    result = self._do_insert(cls._base_manager, using, fields, update_pk, raw)
  File "/home/lenovo/.virtualenvs/gjt/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 963, in _do_insert
    using=using, raw=raw)
  File "/home/lenovo/.virtualenvs/gjt/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/lenovo/.virtualenvs/gjt/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1079, in _insert
    return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(return_id)
  File "/home/lenovo/.virtualenvs/gjt/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1112, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/lenovo/.virtualenvs/gjt/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 79, in execute
    return super(CursorDebugWrapper, self).execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/lenovo/.virtualenvs/gjt/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 64, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/lenovo/.virtualenvs/gjt/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 94, in __exit__
    six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
  File "/home/lenovo/.virtualenvs/gjt/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 64, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/lenovo/.virtualenvs/gjt/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 101, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(query, args)
  File "/home/lenovo/.virtualenvs/gjt/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 205, in execute
    self.errorhandler(self, exc, value)
  File "/home/lenovo/.virtualenvs/gjt/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 36, in defaulterrorhandler
    raise errorclass, errorvalue
django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1364, "Field 'name' doesn't have a default value")
```

What is strange is that even if there's the error it creates the table. I can save objects there and there's also an entry in the `django_migrations` table. Also, `showmigrations` shows that this migrations is done. However, when I run the `migrate` command again I get the same error.

My question is what can cause this problem and how can I solve it? After removing the **STRICT_TRANS_TABLES** from the mysql config file, this error turns to be a warning, but it's still annoying. What causes this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`MySQL` in latest versions has made it mandatory to add default value for `NOT NULL` columns. It is caused due to `STRICT_TRANS_TABLES` mode. There are 3 ways to fix it,

1) Add default value to not null columns.

```
    ALTER TABLE tablename MODIFY columname DATATYPE NOT NULL DEFAULT 'a value'
```

2) Set NULL values by default

```
    ALTER TABLE tablename MODIFY columname DATATYPE NULL
```

3) In `MySQL` configuration file, remove `STRICT_TRANS_TABLES` from `sql_mode` and restart the service.

Comment: Thanks, this was a perfect answer!

Answer (score 0):

I did not need table. I deleted table then ran migrations and migrate again